# How to create a sidebar in magento

Tags: layout

I have the left sidebar which works in `2columns-left` layout.

I have to create a new sidebar, let's call it `left2`.

Inside `2columns-left.phtml` I call it with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left2'); ?>
```

In my `local.xml` I have

```
<cms_page_view translate="label">
   <reference name="left2">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="vertnavcms_mobile" template="catalog/navigation/vertnavcms_mobile.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</cms_page_view>
```

And in my `vertnavcms_mobile.phtml`
I have `<?php echo "hello world" ?>`

But nothing is outputed on frontend (cms page). What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: in which layout you to call this ? 2-col left,3col etc?

Comment: @AmitBera Inside `2columns-left.phtml` I call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left2'); ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, couple of errors here.  Firstly you are referencing a block which you have not yet created, and secondly you are using a layout handle which doesn't actually exist, you need to use `cms_page` to target all cms pages (if you want to target individual cms pages you should add the layout updated when editing the cms page in admin).

The call you have added into the root template is fine:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left2'); ?>
```

but using `reference` in your layout is not correct. This targets an existing block in order to add child blocks to it, you instead need to create an entirely new block.  So in `local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="left2" />
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
    ...
</layout>
```

Notice there is no template set and this is because you are using block type `core/text_list`.  This is a special block type which automatically renders out any child blocks added to it, and that's what you use `reference` in your layout to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...
    <cms_page>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="left2" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="left2">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="vertnavcms_mobile" template="catalog/navigation/vertnavcms_mobile.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
    ...
</layout>
```

or you can use the shorthand method of just defining a `parent` block node attribute in which case you don't need reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ...
    <cms_page>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="left2" parent="root" />
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="vertnavcms_mobile" template="catalog/navigation/vertnavcms_mobile.phtml" parent="left2" />
    </cms_page>
    ...
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to call this block on content area. So you need change reference name

`<reference name="left2">` to `<reference name="content">`

Or 
There are any block exits in name of `left2` at `layout xmls` so it didn't call.So you need create a block name of `left2`  in reference of root  `<reference name="root">`

so,

```
<reference name="root">
 <block type="core/text_list" name="left2" as="left2" translate="label">
                <label>left2 Column</label>
            </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: But this does not create a new sidebar, right? I need a new one, say left2, which will be displayed only on specific pages on mobile.

Comment: this create new leftbat